# Change the highlighting on a stacked bar chart in highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have the following data frame that contains data by group, item, index and hours:

```
data<- data.frame(
  group=c("group_1","group_1","group_2","group_1","group_2","group_2","group_2","group_1"),
  item=c("item_A","item_A","item_C","item_B","item_D","item_D","item_C","item_B"),
  index=c(1,2,1,1,2,3,3,3),
  hours=c(10,20,20,20,30,10,20,10)
)%>%
  arrange(index)
```

and I can plot them as a stacked bar chart in highcharter using the following:

```
hchart(data,
       "column",
       hcaes(x = index, y = hours, group = group),
       tooltip = list(pointFormat = "{point.group} <br> {point.item} <br> Hours: {point.hours}"))%>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(
      dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
      stacking = "normal",
      borderWidth= 0,
      enableMouseTracking = TRUE))%>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "index"))
```

which produces this plot:

[original_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmkaT.png)

I really like the functionality of being able to turn off the groups, by clicking on the "group_1" and "group_2" buttons in the legend and want to keep this. However, when I scroll over the chart, and highlight item_B in index 3 for example, I would like the chart to only highlight the data in item_B instead of highlighting **all** of the data in group_1.

[faded_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAjUP.png)

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you try to change [series.column.states.hover](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.states.hover), [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kw8gx0ct/)?

Comment: Yes I have looked at the guidance, but I think these options refer to the original groups (i.e. the groups specified in group=group) and so the hover settings will be applied to the group variable not the item variable in my example.

Comment: If you have the ability to reproduce the problem in an online code editor, I will be able to better diagnose it.

Comment: Like this? `hchart(data,
       "column",
       hcaes(x = index, y = hours, group = group),
       tooltip = list(pointFormat = "{point.group} <br> {point.item} <br> Hours: {point.hours}"))%>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(
    dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
    stacking = "normal",
    borderWidth= 0,
    enableMouseTracking = TRUE),
    series = list(states = list(inactive = list(opacity = 1))))%>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "index"))`

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately that doesn't help. The key issue here is that I want the highlighting to work on a **subset** of each group (denoted by the same "item" variable), but I want the colours of each group and the clickable tags in the legend to work at the group level and not the subgroup level (in this case the "item" variable).